# Identify this “large TNC” coax connector

Tags: connectors, equipment, dummy-load, military-surplus

I have recently acquired a nice looking dummy load on military surplus sale. Being relatively new to the hobby, I assumed the connector on it was something common. Turns out it is not. So far nobody has been able to tell what it is. The most specific answer I got is that it is a 'large TNC', except I haven't been able to find anything like it. Looking for the model number on the manufacturer’s site also didn't bring up anything useful.

I thought also of replacing the connector entirely, but it turns out that the center pin and dielectric are integral parts of the resistor inside.

Here are a couple of pictures of the load and the connector up close.

[image: The connector]

[image: The connector head on]

[image: The connector diameter]

[image: The load from the side]

[image: The load's model number]

Comment: It might be useful to take a picture of the connector directly end-on, from as far away as still gives decent resolution (for minimum perspective distortion). This will allow people to get dimensions of the subcomponents of the connector from the photo. (On the other hand, if someone already knows it, that probably isn't necessary.)

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO thank you for suggestion. I've just added such a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector is called an "HN" type connector. It has a 3/4-20 thread and it is usable up to 4 GHz. The Amphenol data on it is available [here](https://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/hn-type.html).

[image]

Comment: This might be it! The dimensions are pretty much spot on. Now I just need to find a place which wouldn't charge me $50 for a female connector (these are the prices I can see at local vendors). My best bet might be to drive back to place where I bought the load and dive into their bins of disassembled connectors.

Comment: I can assure you that is the right connector. I looked up the specs on your Bendix 633.8 and then confirmed the dimensions just to be sure.

Comment: Glenn, where were you able to get the spec for the dummy load? I would  be most interested in having a look at those too, to know exactly what I bought.

Comment: Try this link: [link] (http://www.webflis.us/webflis.aspx?NSN=5985-01-034-8226)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a male SC connector and the dimensions seem in the ballpark too.

I found this via a ["Microwave Coaxial Connectors" PDF](http://www.phys.hawaii.edu/~anita/new/papers/militaryHandbook/coax_con.pdf) which describes it as:

> **SC** (OSSC) - The SC coaxial connector is a medium size, older type constant 50 Ω impedance. It is larger than the BNC, but about the same as Type N. It has a frequency range of 0-11 GHz.

This matches what Amphenol says about [their SC-Type Connector Series](https://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/sc-type.html):

> The SC-Type connector series is a medium size, 50 Ω series, with performance up to 11 GHz.
>
> The SC-Type connectors are manufactured to meet MIL-C-39012 category D, specification sheets 35 through 43. The series meets all of the mechanical and electrical requirements of the Limited Co-ordination Specification (LC Spec.) as generated by the U.S. Air Force.
>
> Connector mating is a .687-24 UNEF screw thread.

Tom Williams (WA1MBA) does not show this connector on his [RF Connectors for Upper Frequencies](http://www.wa1mba.org/rfconn.htm) page yet considers it "common":

> There are many other common RF interconnects, but are not described in this treatment because their performance in the microwave region is very limited. Examples are C, HN, **SC**, LC, various EIA, UHF, mini-UHF, Motorola, HV, SHV, and RCA Phono. [emphasis mine]

(Clearly that's a bit at odds with the "up to 11 GHz" frequency range I see cited everywhere else.)

Maury's ["Microwave Coaxial Connector Technology: A Continuing Evolution" PDF](https://www.maurymw.com/pdf/datasheets/5A-021.pdf) also lists it amongst "General purpose coaxial connectors in wide use for systems application" and summarizes it as a

> Threaded version of type C for aircraft and EW applications.

Comment: This looks promising!

Comment: Your Amphenol link shows a conical mating surface (I assume of the dielectric), but the connector in the question photos looks straight-sided in that aspect.

Comment: Indeed, this section is cylindrical in my connector. Also, some of the dimmensions are close, but others differ by as much as 2mm